# Accessing routes.rb from React Component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, routes, jsx

I'm working on a simple Rails project and I'm trying to incorporate React into the front end.  I've installed the `react-rails` gem and have been refactoring with no issue.  However, there is a small inconvenience.  With an ERB view I am able to create links by referencing variables like `root_path` or `login_path` etc. The effect is that I can very simply create links:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

This is ideal because if the `root_path` ever changes this link won't break.

Now that I'm refactoring with React I have to hard code the path in my links:

```
<Link url="/home" title="Home"/>
```

Now if the `root_path` changes these links will break.  Is there a way that I can access routes.rb from within React?  Or a workaround that prevents my links from breaking if the route changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this gem to implement all the rails route helpers for you js app.

https://github.com/railsware/js-routes